# ConstraintLayout in Android Studio - overlapping title bar, but title bar doesn't appear in design view or XML

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout

So, if you build an app in Android Studio, you can of course use ConstraintLayout.  I set the constraints, but often find that when I actually launch the app, the content is under the title bar at the top.  But the title bar isn't apparently something you can access while designing (either in Design or Text view of the layout).

Is there a good way of avoiding this?  Making sure that you don't overlap the title bar on devices?

Comment: Can you add your layout xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use fitSystemWindows flag or xml property in main view.